# jQuery .animate() only animating on return

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I've used .animate() for a div in my design, and although it shows the content, it only shows the animation when closing, not when opening.

You can see it here, when clicking on the German flag on the top-right corner:

http://cccctanger.com/inwx/index-logged-in-actual.html

Any thoughts? Might it be a conflict with other scripts?

```
<div class="pull-right">
<a class="ix-lang" href="#">DE <img src="img/flag-de.png"/></a> 
<span class="ix-lang-more">
<a href="#">EN <img src="img/flag-en.png"/></a> 
<a href="#">ES <img src="img/flag-es.png"/></a>
</span>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
( function( $ ) {
   $( 'a[href="#"]' ).click( function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   } );
} )( jQuery );
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
$("a").tooltip()
    });
</script>

<script>
$("select.ix-select-contact").change(function(){
    $(".ix-show-details").empty();
    $(".ix-show-details").append("<strong>Mario Peschel</strong> · InterNetworX Ltd. & Co. KG<br />Telefon:+49.3066400137  Fax:+49.3066400138<br />E-Mail:mp@inwx.de<br />Berlin, Tempelhofer Damm 140 12099, DE");
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function{
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
})
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ix-btn-custom').popover({ 
    html : true,
    content: function() {
      return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
    }
  });
});
</script>
<script>
$('.ix-lang').click(function(){
$('.ix-lang-more').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 'easeInExpo');})
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code, I don't feel like digging through your site.

Comment: how about a jsfiddle?

Comment: The last script is the animate one, I posted the others just in case they interfere.

Comment: Where is the jsfiddle? Link to website doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  TriggerClick = 0;

  $(".ix-lang").click(function(){
    if(TriggerClick==0){
         TriggerClick=1;
         $(".ix-lang-more").animate({width:'60px'}, "easeInExpo");
    }else{
         TriggerClick=0;
         $(".ix-lang-more").animate({width:'0px'}, "easeInExpo");
    };
  });
```

Comment: Thx aimadnet, but it doesn't open at all with it : /